# Is there a simple way to add a google sign in button to HTML files?

Tags: html, google-cloud-platform, phpmyadmin

I created a google sign in using Google OAuth 2.0, I configure it using Xamp and php to build the database, I built it outside my project, now I want to include the google sign in button in my project but I kept getting errors. From my localhost, I want to add it to my file first and see how it would look in my page before uploading it. Below is my index.php file

```html
<?php
require_once('config.php');
require_once('core/controller.Class.php');

?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="uft-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, inital-scale=1">
<title>Login with Google</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-F3w7mX95PdgyTmZZMECAngseQB83DfGTowi0iMjiWaeVhAn4FJkqJByhZMI3AhiU" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container" style="margin-top: 100px">
    <?php
        if(isset($_COOKIE["id"]) && isset($_COOKIE["sess"])){
            $Controller = new Controller;
            if($Controller -> checkUserStatus($_COOKIE["id"], $_COOKIE["sess"])){
                echo $Controller -> printData(intval($_COOKIE["id"]));
                echo '<a href="logout.php">Logout</a>';
            }else{
                echo "Error!";
            }
            
        }else{

    ?>
    <img src="img/20210908_214559.jpg" alt="Logo"
    style="display: table; margin: 0 auto; max-width: 150px;">

    <form action="" method=:POST>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email Address</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1"
            placeholder="Enter email">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1"
            placeholder="Enter password">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
        <button onClick="window.location = '<?php echo $login_url;?>'" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Login with Google</button>
    </div>
    </form>
        <?php } ?>
        
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're expecting to collect the google username and password and then pass that to the google auth engine? That's not the way I've implemented the solution.
Google provide [instructions](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in) for integrating their sign-in service.
I recommend following those instructions. This will require the following files:

1. A login page which contains the google sign-in button. You could conceivably add this to any of your existing pages. The relevant code is:

```
<div class="g-signin2" data-longtitle="true" data-onsuccess="onSignIn"></div>
```

2. A javascript file which contains the onSignIn function and a signOut function if you want one. This file handles the redirect to a successful logged in page and also passes the attributes you want to collect from the user's Google account. I'm using XMLHttpRequest, but you could use POST if you wish. This page contains the page that the user will be directed to upon successful login, set in xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {}:

```
function onSignIn(googleUser) {
  var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
    var id_token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;
//    console.log('ID: ' + profile.getId()); // Do not send to your backend! Use an ID token instead.
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', 'includes/oauth.php');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        window.location = "../loggedin.php"; //Redirect to loggedin page on completion of oauth.php. Determine if new user or existing user and process accordingly
    }
    xhr.send('idtoken=' + id_token + '&googleId=' + profile.getId() + '&name=' + profile.getName() + '&imageURL=' + profile.getImageUrl() + '&email=' + profile.getEmail());
}

function signOut() {
    gapi.load('auth2', function() {
        gapi.auth2.init().then(function(){
            var auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
            auth2.signOut().then(function () {
                document.location.href = 'includes/logout.php';
            });
        });
    });
}
```

3. A file to handle the authentication (referred to as includes/oauth.php in my javascript file above). Note the settings for $leeway - this caused me a lot of grief figuring out that the clock on my server was slower than the Google auth server's clock!):

```
require_once '../vendor/autoload.php';
$jwt = new \Firebase\JWT\JWT; //Allow for discrepancies between server and auth times
$jwt::$leeway = 60;

$CLIENT_ID = "ENTER_YOUR_CLIENT_ID_HERE";
$client = new Google_Client(['client_id' => $CLIENT_ID]);  // Specify the CLIENT_ID of the app that accesses the backend
$client->setRedirectUri("http://localhost/includes/oauth.php");
$client->addScope("email");
$client->addScope("profile");

if (isset($_POST['idtoken'])){
    $id_token = $_POST['idtoken'];
    $attempt = 0;
    do {
        try {
            $payload = $client->verifyIdToken($id_token);
            $retry = false;
        } catch (Firebase\JWT\BeforeValidException $e) {
            error_log("JWT server time mismatch. Retry attempt: " . strval($attempt) . "Error: " . $e, 0);
            $attempt++;
            $retry = $attempt < 3;
        }
    } while ($retry);

    if ($payload) {
      $userid = $payload['sub'];
      ...
      YOUR VALIDATION, SESSION SETTING, ETC. CODE HERE
      ...
    } else {
      // Invalid ID token
        print("Invalid ID token");
    }
} else {  //Attempt to access this page directly, redirect to Google login page
    $auth_url = $client->createAuthUrl();
    header('Location: ' . filter_var($auth_url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}
```

4. The page that will displayed upon successful login. I used an interstitial page here because the authenticated user could be new to my site and need to create a profile, or could be an existing user and want to go about their activities. I look to verify whether a SESSION has been started and whether this includes a successful authentication.

Comment: I've got everything set up, the config.php, controller.php, index.php, logout.php and even the google-api vendor autoload.php. The real issue i'm having is, i set these up in xampp htdocs, i don't know how to link it to my files just like i'll link my css and javascript. I need some help please, I'm new to this backend stuff @MuppetDance